# how to load 10 gb data dump into a table

Tags: mysql

when i am running the

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:\\Project\\FMCG\\fmcg_event_table_cd.txt'
INTO TABLE fmcg_event_table_cd
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' IGNORE 1 LINES;
```

The file fmcg_event_table_cd.txt file contains 10 GB of data
but we need to take short chunks of this file for loading. can i know the query for loading a large data in one go?

Comment: Better suited for [http://dba.stackexchange.com/](http://dba.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: you should use command line to import the database table manually.

Answer (score 2):

try to use `mysqlimport`

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysqlimport.html

Comment: the .txt file containing large amount of data has first row as column names.how to ignore these column names as the LOAD query is giving following error:"Incorrect integer value: 'ID' for column 'ID' at row 1" and then no result appears. Now i am this by command line client